# Yarn can't run any script

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

When I run `yarn start` or any other following scripts:

```json
"scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --config scripts/webpack.dev.js",
        "clean": "rimraf build",
        "build": "yarn run clean && yarn run compile",
        "compile": "webpack --config scripts/webpack.prod.js",
        "compile-for-test": "webpack --config scripts/webpack.test.prod.js",
        "build-for-test": "yarn run clean && yarn run compile-for-test",
        "test": "jest -c scripts/jest.config.js --testPathIgnorePatterns=\"services/contract-tests\"",
        "test-ci": "node scripts/test-shell-commands.js unitTestCI",
        "test-contract": "node scripts/test-shell-commands.js testLocal",
        "test-contract-ci": "node scripts/test-shell-commands.js testCI",
        "coverage": "node scripts/test-shell-commands.js unitTestCoverage",
        "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --max-warnings=0 \"src/**\"",
        "start-backend": "bash -l ./scripts/start-backend-container.sh",
        "stop-backend": "bash -l ./scripts/stop-backend-container.sh",
        "start-stub": "bash -l ./scripts/start-backend-stub-container.sh",
        "stop-stub": "bash -l ./scripts/stop-backend-stub-container.sh",
        "prettier": "prettier --write **/*{ts,tsx}"
    },
```

I get the following error:

```json
# yarn start
$ webpack-dev-server --config scripts/webpack.dev.js
error Couldn't find the binary webpack-dev-server --config scripts/webpack.dev.js
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

# yarn test
$ jest -c scripts/jest.config.js --testPathIgnorePatterns="services/contract-tests"
error Couldn't find the binary jest -c scripts/jest.config.js --testPathIgnorePatterns="services/contract-tests"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

This applies to all scripts (its not spesific to webpack etc). However, when I use it `npm run start`, it works. `yarn add` or `yarn` commands alone also work. Just I can't run any script with `yarn`.

Does anyone encountered this before?

My yarn version is: `1.22.10`
I have uninstalled and installed a few times but the problem continues. OS: Windows

Comment: Is it possible you've used *non-breaking* spaces?

Comment: I double-checked but it's not the case.

Comment: It seems like `yarn` is not able to find the executable dependencies when you try to run a `script`. I suggest to remove the `node_modules` folder, run `yarn cache clean`. After that run `yarn install` and try to run `yarn start`.

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: @maltoze yes I forgot to specify it

Comment: @MilanTenk thans for suggestion, will try and let you know!

Comment: @MilanTenk Unfortunately same error after your proposition, thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome, I have an other question: Is the installed `Node.js` added to the `PATH` in the environmental variables? 
(You can also check it from command line by running `node --version` from a folder, where the `node.exe` is not there. If `node --version` prints the version, the environmental variable is ok.)

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6086#issuecomment-423423144

Comment: Whats your return on running `yarn config get script-shell`?

Comment: @iLuvLogix after your question I realized it's not looking for correct path.. Please answer with a question and I will accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an issue with node trying to spawn a command on windows when specifying bash as the shell since Yarn uses node's `child_process.spawn`.

The shell-script specified in `.yarnrc`, passes that shell as the shell option to spawn, and when a shell is specified and `process.platform` evaluates to `win32`, `['/d', '/s', '/c'` will be tacked in the arguments (see below source of `spawn()`).

```
 if (options.shell) {
    const command = [file].concat(args).join(' ');

    if (process.platform === 'win32') {
      if (typeof options.shell === 'string')
        file = options.shell;
      else
        file = process.env.comspec || 'cmd.exe';
      args = ['/d', '/s', '/c', `"${command}"`];
      options.windowsVerbatimArguments = true;
```

Please check your yarn configuration via `yarn config get script-shell` in order to verify the settings of the bash-path.

See [child_process.spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) for more info..